# How to put predefined commit message in Gitlab web UI?

Tags: git, gitlab, hook, githooks

I've been created prepare-commit-msg and commit-msg client hooks, that work fine if I make commits from the command line. These hooks add some predefined commit message text. Something like

```
Comment:
JIRA:
Reviewer:
```

The question is - how to enable this message text in Gitlab web UI after modifying a file? I mean - is there any way to put my the above template (Comment, JIRA, Reviewer) as a predefined text in the input field (see a picture).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, you have:

- [description templates](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/description_templates.html#description-templates) for issues
- [service templates](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/services_templates.html#services-templates) for projects

But I don't even see a commit message template in the [feature requests proposals](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues?label_name%5B%5D=feature%20proposal).